# syntax support for es6 (default params) in visual studio 2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, syntax-highlighting, default-parameters

I am trying to use the default parameters in the javascript function parameters

```
  var _BindAddNewPipelineButton = function(pipeId = undefined, enableEditMode = false) {
```

Its not recognizing proper syntax highlighting and breaking my javascript file.

[image]

Please let me know any plugins available to support this kind of highlighting

---

Cant see the Language Service. Please see screenshot
[image]

Comment: You don't have to specify undefined for params if you are not passing it'll be undefined by default.

Comment: ok removed that , now , even false is breaking . like this.  var _BindAddNewPipelineButton = function(pipeId, enableEditMode = false) {

Comment: syntax is correct which browser and version you are using?

Comment: no no , everything is working fine .my syntax is breaking in visual studio editor and hence all my auto indentation and intellisemse support is not working

Answer (score 0):

For VS2015:

Open Tools > Options > Text editor > Node.js > IntelliSense and select the ES6 IntelliSense Preview checkbox.

Maybe you will have to install TypeScript 1.6 before doing this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/ES6-IntelliSense-Preview-in-NTVS-1.1

For VS2017:

Have you checked 'Enable the new JavaScript language service' (Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Language Service)?

I disabled this once because of low performance issues and I had the same problem as you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know there wasn't a section for that in VS 2015. See my updated answer and please consider to upvote it if you find it useful.